# How do I get rid of "weknow.ac"?

Tags: macbook-pro, web-browser

I somehow got this annoying 'weknow.ac' file in my MacBook while updating some Flash player. I tried several ways to get rid of it like checking extensions and by installing Malwarebytes. Nothing worked so far.

Did anyone face this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the Flash update you installed was fake, I would suggest you immediately stop using secure sites like online shopping and banking.

Personally I am probably a bit paranoid, so I would be worried about any other stuff that has been installed and would be looking to do a Anti Virus scan and backing up all my data and reinstalling the operating system.

However looking online it appears that these fake Flash installers typically just install a few browser extensions and a security profile.

The extensions you seem to have handled, but the security profile requires a little more work....

1. Go to System Preferences.
2. Click Profiles.
3. The list will include an item "AdminPrefs".
4. Select this and click the remove `-` button in the lower left corner.

This will remove the security profile, you should then check all browsers, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Opera (if you have these installed) and remove the extension/verify it is removed.

Then finally finish up by resetting the browser settings for these browsers, to avoid repeating this information I'll reference this article for that:
https://www.bugsfighter.com/remove-weknow-ac-mac/

Again I would be mindful that while this is how you are able to remove this malware, I would personally be concerned and would be looking to backup and reinstall my operating system.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the suggestion. This weknow.ac seem to have gone now. But my browsers home page is weird. I though it is because of weknow. [Here is the screenshot](https://imgur.com/zghhcl9). Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, something on the system is redirecting your browser to a different home page, have you tried resetting Chrome? Google's instructions: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en-GB

Comment: Yeah I tried it. But every time I reset the chrome, weknow is showing up in the "manage search engines" section. I'm a little worried now :(

Comment: There is no way to be 100% sure but I suspect it's just adware looking to redirect search and what not to make money, however you should be considering backing up data and reinstalling your mac.

Comment: @bionerd it looks like weknow.ac simply changed the default search engine and/or the start page of Chrome; can you change it back (to Google/whatever you had before)? If not, your only option might be to reinstall the OS like unknowndomain suggested.

Comment: @11684 How do you know it only changed the search engine?

Comment: @Mark I don’t know, but Bionerd wrote “this weknow.ac seem to have gone now”. If that is true, this is just a settings change that remained.

Comment: @11684 or the virus writer is cleaver - allow you to think you have removed it but leave another hook in place.

Comment: System Preferences/Profiles?

Comment: @mark's point is why personally I would always rebuild the system if this happened to me, it's not worth the risk, especially as someone who uses a password manager, I don't know how they work, but would hate for them to grab my passwords because I didn't bother to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [this](https://unboxhow.com/cybersecurity/remove-weknow-ac-from-mac) article worked for me. There are several basic guidelines that you can follow to remove it from your machine.

Step 1. Ending Process Running Under The “Activity Monitor”

Step 2. Remove Weknow.ac virus Malicious Apps From Mac OS

Step 3. Remove Weknow.ac virus Apps From Auto-Startup

Step 4. Remove Weknow.ac virus Daemons And Agents From Mac’s Startup

Step 5. Uninstall Weknow.ac virus Or Unwanted/Suspicious Extensions From If Added Browsers

Step 6. Restart the browser.

You can find step by step guidelines here: [remove weknow.ac](https://unboxhow.com/cybersecurity/remove-weknow-ac-from-mac)

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Thank you for your answer, but please be aware that the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers. You may want to read [Expected Behavior](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) for more info. Thanks again for sharing your knowledge! :)